# How can I force Make to execute a recipe all the time

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The current Makefile has something like this:

```
target1 : lib1.a  lib2.a

target2 : lib1.a  lib3.a

target3 : lib3.a 

lib1.a:
    $(MAKE) -C sub_dir all
```

I want to change this Makefile so that wherever a target depends on `lib1.a`, it always run the command "`$(MAKE) -C sub_dir all`", always. Another words, in the above example, target1 and target2 will always run "`$(MAKE) -C sub_dir all`". Is there any way I can do that?

I know the following does not work:

```
target1 :  lib2.a
    $(MAKE) -C sub_dir all

target2 :   lib3.a
    $(MAKE) -C sub_dir all

target3 : lib3.a
```

Because if lib2.a has no update, the the command does not run. I have one restriction, I only control lib1.a, I cannot change how lib2.a is built.

Any help is appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**: I used the following solution:

```
target1 : lib1.a  lib2.a

target2 : lib1.a  lib3.a

target3 : lib3.a 

lib1.a: relay

.PHONY: relay
relay:
    $(MAKE) -C sub_dir all
```

The [GNU Make help](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html) says that FORCE is not as efficient as .PHONY, but from your explanation, it seems to me FORCE is better. Do I mis-understand?

Comment: You can add `.PHONY: lib1.a` but this will cause all the targets to be relinked all the time.

Comment: make target depend on something (the sub_dir?) that in turn depends on lib1.a

Answer (score 34):

I think a [`Force Target`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets) is what you are looking for here.

```
lib1.a: FORCE
        $(MAKE) -C sub_dir all

FORCE: ;
```

As compared to a `.PHONY` rule (as suggested by @MadScientist [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226106/how-can-i-force-to-run-a-command-all-the-time#comment41133336_26226106)) this will not in-and-of-itself force all the targets that depend on `lib1.a` to rebuild all the time. It will only do that if `lib1.a` actually changes.

A better solution though is likely to get rid of the sub-make entirely and actually have the dependency information for `lib1.a` available to this makefile (either directly or via an included makefile in `sub_dir`) because that avoids this entire "force this recipe because I can't tell you how to tell if the target needs updating" problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you suggest to use a _Force Target_ over a _Phony Target_? The link to the GNU manual you posted seems to suggest the opposite. "As you can see, using ‘FORCE’ this way has the same results as using ‘.PHONY: clean’.

Using ‘.PHONY’ is more explicit and more efficient. However, other versions of make do not support ‘.PHONY’; thus ‘FORCE’ appears in many makefiles"